# Please [Enter Image Description Here]

Tags: support, images

When someone attaches a picture to their post, the SE system automatically attaches a tooltip *Enter image description here*, inviting the poster to give some alt-text for the image.

These tips are easy to overlook and the description is often not entered.

However, alt-text is used by browsers for the sight-impaired.  The text is presented or spoken to the reader.

Several of our posts are being provided with alt-text, so thanks to those posters who are doing it, but there are a few without.
As I've said above, it is easy to overlook and no blame can be assigned.

Can I suggest we try to assist as many visitors to the site as possible by adding image descriptions.  Just a word or two is all that is required.

Also, feel free to edit existing posts to add descriptions.  I've done a couple but there are more to do.
Find them with search such as:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Aretrocomputing.stackexchange.com+%22enter+image+description+here%22

While we are a young site we can set an example to the rest of SE.
The issue is neither new nor unique to us - see for example [ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/call-to-action-fill-in-image-descriptions)

Comment: I agree with you, but your search returns user profiles, such as [this one](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/65/ardaozkal). I have no clue where the image is, but it's probably not worth changing anyway.

Comment: @Laurel. Interesting find, yes you can't change a profile. The search needs a tweak.

Comment: @Chenmunka See [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aretrocomputing.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22enter+image+description+here%22&ia=web).